# HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to integrate external jar file into my project. (mambu-models-V3.8.10.jar)

But I receive such error message:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mambu/loans/shared/model/LoanAccount    


org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mambu/loans/shared/model/LoanAccount
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1287)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

root cause:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mambu.loans.shared.model.LoanAccount
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1962)
com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:662)
com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:356)
com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:151)
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:585)
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:543)
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:529)
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:847)
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:853)
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:967)
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1000)
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:961)
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
com.mambu.apisdk.MambuAPIFactory.getLoanService(MambuAPIFactory.java:86)
comm.app.starter.HomeController.Opaaaaana(HomeController.java:167)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Here is my POM xml:

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.springapp
    kapiv2
    war
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    kapi

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mambu</groupId>
        <artifactId>mambumodels</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.10</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/mambu-models-V3.8.10.jar
        </systemPath>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
   <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cenqua.clover</groupId>
        <artifactId>clover</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
   <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>kapi</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

There are a lot of results in google if you search NoClassDefFoundError - but none of them hellped me.

could you please tell me why I receive such error?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that jar file that was needed for running this function was missing in run time. So I added this to MAVEN

```
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/myTESTapplication/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the dependency in system scope. That means, when you code the app your ide will have it nicely there as dependency, but when running the code, the server should have it under classpath or some lib folder before it finds the dependency to run correctly. In this scope maven and tomcat don't do any tricks on your behalf.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html is tomcat reference about classpath and it suggests WEB-INF/lib for the jar location under your webapp, when system scope is used. If you do want use the maven to provide the class for you, you should use compile target and have a repo for providing the jar for you. More at [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: in eclipse maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670749/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-in-eclipse-maven) .

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not be that the class is missing - it may be present, but failed to initialise correctly. e.g. An exception occurred in a static code block.

This answer explains it well [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was setting a `static final String` that was throwing an exception and causing this error, hardcoding this value solved the issue:

```
private static final String SERVICE_NAME = ManifestProvider.getServiceName();
```